# What is the correct way to create an already-completed CompletableFuture<Void>

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, completable-future

I am using Completable futures in java 8 and I want to write a method that, based on a received parameter, either runs multiple tasks with side effects in parallel and then return their "combined" future (using `CompletableFuture.allOf()`), or does nothing and returns an already-completed future.

However, `allOf` returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`:

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> allOf(CompletableFuture<?>... cfs)
```

And the only way to create an already-completed future that  know is using `completedFuture()`, which expects a value:

```
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> completedFuture(U value)
```

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is already completed with the given value.

and `Void` is uninstantiable, so I need another way to create an already-completed future of type `CompletableFuture<Void>`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Since `Void` can not be instantiated, you can only complete a `CompletableFuture<Void>` with a `null` result, which is exactly what you also will get when calling `join()` on the future returned by `allOf()` once it has been successfully completed.

So you can use

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
```

to get such an already completed future.

But you can also use

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.allOf();
```

to denote that there are no jobs the result depends on. The result will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 18):

pass a `null` I guess:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> done = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
```