# CompletionStage, CompletableFuture Void - what to return?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactive, completable-future

Here is my method :

```
public CompletionStage<Void> insert(List<HashAction> hashActionList) {
    if(!hashActionList.isEmpty()) {
        return ...
    }
    // what to return here ?
}
```

I have no idea of what to return if my list is empty. Not sure that null is good since I would have to check for null afterwards.

I tried

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
```

But I'm not really convinced since I chose randomly one implementation of CompletionStage

Comment: Throw an exception? Does it make sense to call it with an empty list? What is your normal return value? Why is it the method async at all?

Comment: Having an empty list is a correct use case so I can't really throw an exception. This method is async because it inserts data into a mongo collection. My normal return value is void

Comment: `CompletableFuture` is the _de facto_ implementation of `CompletionStage`. So much so that the `CompletionStage` interface has a method whose sole purpose is to turn it into a `CompletableFuture`: [`#toCompletableFuture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#toCompletableFuture()). It's also the only public implementation provided by Java SE. My point being that returning `CompletableFuture` is not suspect. Besides, since your method returns `CompletionStage` it shouldn't matter what implementation is actually returned.

Comment: What exactly would happen, if you just remove the `!hashActionList.isEmpty()` and perform whatever is in that block regardless of whether the list is empty or not? Would it already do the right thing? In case you are just trying to optimize the empty list case, return the equivalent of what you return in the unoptimized case. See also [What is the correct way to create an already-completed `CompletableFuture<Void>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642974/2711488)

Comment: what are you going to return if the `hashActionList` is not empty?

Comment: I use MongoDB and insertMany does not accept an empty list

Answer (score 1):

You can just return `CompletableFuture<Void>` by just having empty async run method

```
public CompletionStage<Void> insert(List<String> hashActionList) {
    if(!hashActionList.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{});
}
```

OR you can use `thenAccept` to return `CompletionStage<Void>` and avoid null

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null).thenAccept(i->{});
```

Comment: Returning `null`  when the return type is `CompletionStage` seems counter-intuitive. Personally, I view it the same as returning `null` when the return type is `Optional`.

Comment: What’s the point of calling `runAsync(()->{})` or `thenAccept(i->{})`? That’s just wasting resources for eventually resulting in something that is not different to `completedFuture(null)`.